# Проблема при подключении внешней DLL в VBA

Tags: excel, access, vba, office

У меня стоит office 2016 x64 и почему-то при попытке использовать внешнюю DLL у меня ругается, что DLL не найдена.
Я пробовал явно указывать путь, но не помогло.

На Office 2010 x32 все нормально работает.

Единственное отличие кода-это использование ptrsafe в x64.

В чем может быть проблема? Разве x32 не полностью совместим с х64? Да и ошибка была бы другая, я думаю, если бы дело было в разрядности.

Answer (score 2):

Для использования внешней DLL в 64-х разрядном офисе сама DLL должна быть 64-х разрядной. Увы, 32-х разрядные DLL работать не будут. Именно поэтому в 64-х разрядном офисе исчезла поддержка большинства ActiveX компонентов, доступных в 32-х разрядном офисе.

Если возможности перекомпилировать DLL нет,  то можно попробовать обойти эту проблему через создание 64-х разрядной заглушки, 32-х разрядной обертки и обмениваться данными между ними через IPC. Например, [вот здесь есть описание](https://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/), но, боюсь, решение будет слишком сложным.